# Why i can't change the version of the project faclet?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, web.xml, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-wtp

I have simple project that implements the CRUD action on a local db, using both Spring and hibernate, but as soon as i add the project to the apache tomcat server (ver. 8.5.45) eclipse shows the following: "Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.1."

I tried to change the version of the facet in the project properties but i can't press the apply button.
I even tried to change the version inside the web.xml file but still haven't found a solution

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a checkbox in front of the "Dynamic Web Module". You need to uncheck it first in order to be able to change the version.